# How to check if a variable is defined in Octave?

Tags: variables, undefined, octave

When writing a script that loads data, it's a waste of time to wait for it to load each time.

How to check to see if the variable is defined?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `exist` function in Octave to do the work. It can be used to check the existence of given name as a variable, built in function, file, or directory. In you case, to check the existence of a variable, you may use something like this:

```
if (exist("your_var_name", "var") == 1)
    printf("varname exists");
else
    printf("varname not exists");
endif
```

You may refer the following links for detailed information:

- [Built-in Function: exist (name, type)](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/exist.html)
- [Status of Variables](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_66.html)

Comment: It should be if (exist("varname", "var") == 1)

Answer (score 6):

Need to put the variable name in quotes too,

exist("varname", "var")

Answer (score 2):

```
if (exist("itemcount") == 1)
  % here it checks if itemcount is a variable, by changing the value after ==, you can check for function name, file name, dir, path etc.
end
```

Note itemcount is in double quotes.

By changing the value after ==, you can check for function name, file name, dir, path etc.

from / more info at:
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Status-of-Variables.html#XREFexist

other return values ..
2 if the name is an absolute file name, an ordinary file in Octave’s path, or (after appending ‘.m’) a function file in Octave’s path, 3 if the name is a ‘.oct’ or ‘.mex’ file in Octave’s path, 5 if the name is a built-in function, 7 if the name is a directory, or 103 if the name is a function not associated with a file (entered on the command line). Otherwise, return 0.