# How to check if a function is defined in Octave?

Tags: function, octave

How can I check if octave recognises a function that I have defined in the command line (or a script file)?

For example, how could I check that the function below, `vl`, is defined in octave?

```
function retval = vl(t)
   retval = vl0()+al()*t;
endfunction
```

I found only this post [about how to check variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542628/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-octave)
There, someone uses the command `exist("varname","var")` but there is no option `"func"` so that I can make `exist("vl","func")`; I found only the option `"builtin"` for built-in functions.

Comment: How have you created `retval`? Is it in a file named `retval.m` or is it a local or nestd function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer myself. I hope it will be useful.
In the manual of octave I found that you can call `exist("function name")` without option—that's the point— and the return value for an existing function defined through script or in terminal is `103` (See [return codes of "exist"](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/exist.html)).

Example: In my case

```
exist("vl")
103
```